# Get computed property and pass its value while editing another text field vue.js

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I want to send over a computed property at the same time as editing a textfield so there is no button to "save" however I cannot work out how to get the property value from another field or from the computed data to pass over.

Here is my code so far, activeNote.id can be viewed in the template no problem but I want to pass its value whenever I type into the textarea

```
<template>
  <div class="editor">
    <form id="editForm">
      <h2>Edit</h2>
      <button @click="closeEdit()">Close</button>
      <textarea
        v-bind:value="activeNote.text"
        @input="editNote"
        class="form-control"
      ></textarea>
      <input v-bind:value="activeNote.id" name="id" readonly />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    // not sure this is best practice to dispatch from here
    editNote(e) {
      this.$store.dispatch('editNote', e)
       // activeNote.id doesnt work here unfortunatly
      this.$store.dispatch('noteId', activeNote.id)
      //console.log(activeNote.id)
    }
    closeEdit() {
      //console.log('emitclose')
      this.$emit('closeEdit')
    }
  },
  computed: mapState({
    activeNote: state => state.activeNote
  })
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Use `v-model` instead of `v-bind:value` + `@input="editNote"` is unnecessary.

Comment: sorry but that will just stop the update from happening and wouldn't resolve the issue of passing the second value, I am not using a button to trigger capturing the input

Comment: It should work because `mapState` is reactive two-way. If you insist on using `editNote`, you should change `activeNote.id` to `this.activeNote.id` plus unless you are doing async operations, you should use mutation to update it, not an action.

Comment: Updates are realtime cross devices.  Are you saying change this. In the template or the script section?

Comment: in your `editNote` method

Comment: oh thanks I thought I ha tried that... getting somewhere now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple in the end so fyi the changed code that worked, adding this.

```
<template>
  <div class="editor">
    <form id="editForm">
      <h2>Edit</h2>
      <button @click="closeEdit()">Close</button>
      <textarea
        v-model="activeNote.text"
        @input="editNote"
        class="form-control"
      ></textarea>
      <input v-bind:value="activeNote.id" name="id" readonly />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    editNote(e) {
      this.$store.dispatch('editNote', e)
      this.$store.dispatch('noteId', this.activeNote.id)
    },
    closeEdit() {
      this.$emit('closeEdit')
    }
  },
  computed: mapState({
    activeNote: state => state.activeNote
  })
}
</script>
```